# How to define a global variable in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use global variables in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368877/how-to-use-global-variables-in-objective-c)

I want to know how can i define global variable in Objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the definition of singleton.

Comment: This is the best approach to attack this problem.Here's a link explaining what a singleton is http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use app-delegate or create shared instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. App delegate
2. Singleton

(Well, actually 2.5, since simply using a static variable is a more primitive version of singleton.)

Answer (score -1):

You should create a header file like

```
  // Constants.h
    extern NSString * const Constant1;
    extern NSString * const Constant2;
```

You can include this file in each file that uses the constants or in the pre-compiled header for the project.

You define these constants in a .m file like

```
// Constants.m
NSString * const Constant1 = @"FirstConstant";
NSString * const Constant2 = @"SecondConstant";
```